# A question on empty set and Russell's paradox

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Suppose $S$ is a well-defined set and $A$ is meant to be a subset of $S$ that is defined as follows:

$A = \{x|(x\in S)\wedge(x\not\in S)\}$.

Is $A$ the empty set $\varnothing$, since it is based on the predicate $FALSE$, or is its definition a manifestation of Russell's paradox? I emphasize that $S$ is a well-defined set.

Comment: It is empty; otherwise, the Axiom Schema of Restricted Comprehension would lead to a contradiction.

Comment: You have indeed defined $A=\emptyset$.  Nothing here seems at all related to Russell's paradox.

Comment: Rather than "well-defined" you should say that $S$ is a pre-existing set.

Comment: Thanks Hayden, hardmath and  Asaf Karagila for U'r quick responses. Thanks Hayden and hardmath for reinforcing what I strongly felt should be the case. I had entertained some doubts because I had felt that I may have overlooked some philosophical considerations. Thanks Asaf. $S$ is indeed a pre-existing set.

Comment: Rather than "pre-existing", what you should say is that $S$ is a set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: to me, "well-defined" is clearer than "pre-existing" (although Andres Caicedo's suggestion is better than both). In a set-theoretical context, how can "pre-existing" mean more than "existing"? And how can "an existing set" mean more than "a set"?

Comment: @Tony: "Well-defined" might implies that we need a definition for the set, whereas a "pre-existing" is really just an existing set, whose existence was already given to us. I do agree with Andres, however, that "set" is definitely the better term. In any case, "well-defined", as I said, seems to hint that there is a "definition" which may or may not exist.

Answer (score 2):

The empty set $\emptyset$ is defined as follows: 
$$\forall x: x\notin \emptyset$$

Your set A is as a subset of $S$ where:

$$\forall x:[x\in A \iff x\in S\land x\notin S]$$

It is easy prove that $A=\emptyset$.

Another common construction of an empty subset $B$ of $S$:

$$\forall x:[x\in B \iff x\in S \land x\ne x]$$

Likewise, we can prove $B=\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan Christensen for the alternative definitions of $\varnothing$. What I find particularly useful in your answer is the logical basis of the definition of $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition

$A = \{x|(x\in S)\wedge(x\not\in S)\}$

is not a valid definition of a set in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (and in general, $\{x|\phi(x)\}$ is not a valid definition for any predicate $\phi$). To make it valid, you need to restrict $x$ to a set $T$, like this:

$A = \{x \in T|(x\in S)\wedge(x\not\in S)\}$

In your case, you can take $T$ to be $S$:

$A = \{x \in S|(x\in S)\wedge(x\not\in S)\}$

This is now a valid definition of a set $A$, which turns out to be the empty set $\varnothing$.

Comment: Enlighten me please, TonyK. I do understand the problem with $\{x|\phi(x)\}$, because $\phi(x)$ cannot be any predicate. But if we define $A$ as $\{x\in S|(x\in S)\wedge (x\not\in S)\}$ then are we not defining it as a set of predicates rather than a set of objects? I regard the expression $x\in S$, in my limited knowledge, as a predicate.

Comment: Enlighten me please, TonyK. I do understand the problem with $\{x|\phi(x)\}$, because $\phi(x)$ cannot be any predicate. But if we define $A$ as $\{x\in S|(x\in S)\wedge (x\not\in S)\}$ then are we not defining it as a set of predicates rather than a set of objects? I regard the expression $x\in S$, in my limited knowledge, as a predicate. What is wrong with my definition, since the predicate $(x\in S)\wedge (x\not\in S)$ simply turns out to be $FALSE$ by the law of contradiction?

Comment: @user24098: You didn't ask specifically about ZF set theory in your OP, so perhaps my answer is irrelevant to your question. But ZF has a list of axioms which tell you how you can define sets, and your definition is not covered by any of the axioms. So it is not a valid definition in ZF. That's all.

Comment: Thanks TonyK. You are right. My OP was based on simple set theory. However, I meant to avoid the possibility of $S$ being an element of itself. This is why I started with the vague notion that $S$ is a well-defined set. Your pointing me to the ZF set theory is an important contribution though. I am, as a consequence of this contribution, taking a serious look at the ZF set theory. Cheers!